How to configure Dependabot for non-Semantic Versioning
I regularly use Depandabot and it works fine, especially for Maven dependencies. So I turned it on for Docker package-ecosystem as well and I am facing version issues now.
How to configure Dependabot for versions that do not strictly follow Semantic Versioning?
For example:
I have a docker file with:
FROM ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-21.0.3_9-jre

Obviously, there is a problem, that the version has the prefix open- and the postfix -jre.
Dependabot suggests:
FROM ibm-semeru-runtimes:open-22.0.1_8-jre

I would like to watch only patches. Normally, I comment on the pull request with @dependabot ignore this major version, but it does work for this case. Is there any option to handle that?
